# CSS Downscale IMG only, on firefox

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome, firefox

I have

```
.postImg {
    text-align: center;
}

.postImg img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Which on Chrome downscales images when the window is downscaled, but does not upscale the image past it's width. Which I the desired behaviour.

But on Firefox the images don't get downscaled and stay the same size.
Putting width: 100%; in there ensures the Firefox downscaling, but upscales all smaller images, which is what I don't want.

I must have missed something basic here. And I do not know the size of the image beforehand.

Comment: What sort of element is .postImg? Could you try setting a `width` on there, or setting it to `display: block;` to see if it makes any difference? Can you put up a JSFiddle or similar to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Works for me when I do this: http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/J935P/1/ Is your setup different?

Comment: When I copy my code in the fiddle it doesn't work, but there is so much stuff I can't figure out what's to blame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, grand parent of the .postLeft had

```
display: inline-block;
*display: inline;
```

Which actually did nothing just broke the images.